# Redactor wysiwyg - why does paste from word not working

Tags: jquery, redactor

I've been using the Redactor Wysiwyg editor on a job post form. However, though their website mentions super cleaning on paste from word, I get a lot of extra empty `<p>` and `<br />`, even though in the word markup there is a single paragraph break. Any ideas what might be causing that?  Anybody else has the same problem?

Thanks!
Maria

Comment: they offer support only for the most expensive version and I really cannot afford that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set `paragraphy` and `linebreaks` settings like this :

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    linebreaks: true,
    paragraphy: false
});
```

Comment: This also seemed to fix my issue when pasting would not work in IE 10 (and all IE versions, I believe) for Redactor v9.1.7.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, some text or paragraphs was disappearing when I paste from Word to Redactor 10 in Internet Explorer. There the solution worked for me:

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    pasteCallback: function(html) {
        html = html.replace("<font>", ""); // Fix Word to IE
        html = html.replace("</font>", ""); // Fix Word to IE
        return html;
    },
});
```

When I remove `<font>` tag generated by Microsoft Word before the paste, everything work fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#editor").redactor({
    pasteBeforeCallback: function (html) {
        return html.replace(/<p>\s*<\/p>/g, " ");
    }
});
```